# Disable of RETURNING on INSERT in postgres

Tags: postgresql

`postgres` make it possible to return inserted primary keys using the `RETURNING` clause. Is it possible to disable that functionality? I mean, if someone tries to fetch inserted ids using `RETURNING` it returns nothing. (as common INSERT)
?

Comment: I can't answer your question as asked but I suspect it doesn't have that functionality.  You might be barking up the wrong tree here with your design anyway - maybe look at writing a database function to do the insert or just write a small bit of middleware to securely protect your database from its users.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the INSERT command can not do this.

Some alternatives:

- revoke insert from users and create a function with "SECURITY DEFINER" which do INSERTs, or
- use column level privileges: here the documentation from INSERT command:

  > Use of the RETURNING clause requires SELECT privilege on all columns mentioned in RETURNING. If you use the query clause to insert rows from a query, you of course need to have SELECT privilege on any table or column used in the query.

**UPDATE**:
With column level privileges do at least two things:

- revoke select columns: REVOKE SELECT (restricted_col1, ...) ON TABLE testtable FROM testuser
- revoke insert columns: REVOKE INSERT (restricted_col1, ...) ON TABLE testtable FROM testuser. In this case the restricted_col1 must have DEFAULT value or must havent NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: Correct: you revoke SELECT appropriately.